# Android Error: This class should be public [Instantiatable]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm facing some trouble with android studio, my coding is fine, and it worked when I run to device, but somehow its error when I `generate signed APK`

here are the error messages:

```
Error:(25) Error: This class should be public (com.myapp.SoundLevelView) [Instantiatable]
```

heres my coding :

```
public SoundLevelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            mGreen  = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.greenbar);
            mRed    = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.redbar);

            mWidth  = mGreen.getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMinimumWidth(mWidth*10);

            mHeight = mGreen.getIntrinsicHeight();
            setMinimumHeight(mHeight);

            //Used to paint canvas background color
            mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
            mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
```

I try to disable Lint from Android Preferences and add

```
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
```

to my grade. inside android tag. but its seems not work either. 
anybody facing the same problem as me?

Note: I try to `Invalidated Cache and Restart` too, but not working

Comment: I think you need an empty constructor. Like `public SoundLevelView() {}`.

Comment: @AkshayChordiya if i add that, its error "Theres is no default constructor available in 'android.view.View'

Comment: You need to declare the class as public class SoundLevelView

Comment: when debugging working fine? Please share me the build.gradle

Comment: @GabeSechan my bad man. i forgot set public my parent class. thanks its worked. how can i mark as answer your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class SoundLevelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            mGreen  = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.greenbar);
            mRed    = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.redbar);

            mWidth  = mGreen.getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMinimumWidth(mWidth*10);

            mHeight = mGreen.getIntrinsicHeight();
            setMinimumHeight(mHeight);

            //Used to paint canvas background color
            mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
            mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
```